# how to use liquid swipe in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

I want to implement [this animation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe/master/Screenshots/animation.gif) in project.I search a lot and  found these  links to  solve my problem on [git hub here](https://github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android) and [here](https://github.com/Chrisvin/LiquidSwipe). But these are in Kotlin projects. I  could not use them. Any expert here who  can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to decompile the Kotin to java code. IntelliJ or Android Studio has this feature already. Go to:

Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Decompile Kotlin to Java